# Protractor - how to call the WebDriver methods?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to use the [deleteAllCookies() function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-webdriver-webdriver-options-prototype-deleteallcookies) from WebDriver from a Protractor test spec.

I've tried:

```
browser.driver.deleteAllCookies(); // undefined error
browser.driver.options.deleteAllCookies(); // undefined error
browser.manage().deleteAllCookies(); // doesn't seem to be deleting cookies
```

How do I call/use this function correctly?

Comment: I found this: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5101 where it seems to be a problem with selenium. The issue is IE specific. Do you have a bit more details about your config, which browsers are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm testing in Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();` works OK for me, Chrome & Firefox, Windows or Ubuntu 14.04 or any Ubuntu I tried. I have a test that clears cookies then `browser.navigate().refresh();` to pick the changes since that triggers a login redirect after cookies cleared.

Comment: If doing the page refresh still doesn't work for you i guess next step is to provide more context for your failing scenario: Protractor version, selenium version, Chrome version, a bit more code on the spec file.

Comment: browser.manage().deleteAllCookies(); This is not working for me and it was working before. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me with protractor 1.5.0, selenium-webdriver: "2.44.0"
`browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`

Comment: Is it recommended to use it afterEach function() in protractor ?

Comment: In my opinion, it is a good way to delete cookies in afterEach() in order to prevent cookies from affecting following tests.

Answer (score 4):

In protractor the way to delete all your cookies is:

```
ptor.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: The OP alreadty tried that. `browser` is the new name (for a few months) of the old `ptor` variable.

Comment: `browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();` does work for me, maybe was fixed/changed in a newer version